# Weird backticks string behavior in ES6

Tags: string, ecmascript-6, parameter-passing, backticks

Why the string parameter behaves differently depending on how it was defined?

```
function a(s) {
    console.log(...s)
}
a (`cde`)  //prints c d e
a ('cde')  //prints c d e
a `cde`    //prints cde
a 'cde'    //returns Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string. WHY???
```

If both of these return "string", why the different behavior?

```
typeof(`cde`)  //string
typeof('cde')  //string
```

Comment: `a \`cde\`` is tagged template literal syntax meaning `a('cde')`. `a 'cde' ` is just a syntax error has nothing to do with ho you "define" string

Comment: @YuryTarabanko "*meaning `a('cde')`*" - no, it means `a(['cde'])` (detailed semantics are even more complicated, it's the same immutable array in each call). Notice the OP used spread syntax in his `console.log` call.

Comment: @Bergi, yeah right.